# How to collect data and pass it around

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I should find another interest because this one is taking the life out of me quickly.  Seems like a lot of people are confused about the intricacies of MFC code, including me.  I have an MFC Dialog Box application that creates several dialogs that you navigate to using the typical back or next function.  Along the way you collect data via radio group buttons, list boxes and various other controls.  For the most part I understand how to get a handle on the data by using the m_  variables provided by the AFX maps throughout the code for each distinct dialog.  At the end - and sometimes during - the data collection/selection process gathered by dialogs, I need to do things with what has been collected.  I may need to take the data from one dialog and modify the next based on the previous.  It seems like when you move through the dialogs the data from the last is lost unless you save it somehow.  I know that there are dozens of ways to do this and I have toyed with several of them, from object passing, to creating new classes, new structures, global variables, pointers, whatever.... My concern is, I need a data structure of some sort to stay up and active in memory long enough for my user code to do something with it.  That is the problem I think, I don't know in MFC how to deal with this.  I have currently decided to go with a struct called dlg_DataHandler (to house collected data from each dialog) with a few test members in a .h file.  It has been typedef'd as a pointer.  I am creating a variable of this type and setting it = new dlg_DataHandler, but the data isn't getting passed around like I want from dialog to dialog.  One thing that I wonder about is, I don't know exactly where to place the "new" statement for creating the variable. Its as if data is not flowing to and from the structure as it should.  Anyway here is some of the code:

```
// file1.h

typedef struct dlg_DataHandler {

    int var;
    char* String;
    int RepetitionRadio;  // radio button data
       constructor here
} *dlgDataHandler;

extern dlgDataHandler DlgData;
//*****************



// file2.cpp  

dlg_DataHandler DlgData = new dlg_DataHandler;    // not located anywhere in peticular just in the code since I DON'T KNOW where to put it.  DlgData->member gets loaded in the dialog .cpp files to try collect data, but it doesnt seem to be passing data across the different windows.
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable in your main application class (the one derived from `CWinApp`) and call `new` in `InitInstance()`. You can then use [AfxGetApp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9f064x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to gain access to the application instance, and so your variable, from anywhere else in the code.